# Normalization using Double

Tags: java, double, rounding

I have a group of doubles with a varying number of decimal places. I have a need to get the SUM() of those values and then normalize them all so that they SUM() to 1. Furthermore I have a requirement that in the final results we limit the number of decimal places to 4. To accomplish this I have tried doing the following :

```
normalizationFactor = 1/sumOfAllDoublesInGroup;

for(Object myObject : myGroupOfObjects){
     myObject.setDoubleValue = round(myObject.getDoubleValue * normalizationFactor),4);
}

private Double round (Double doubleValue, Integer decimalPlaces) {
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
    bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return bd.doubleValue();
}
```

The drawback here is that after rounding I still cannot guarantee that the SUM() of all the doubles is still == 1. I would appreciate some help with that.

To be clear the only requirements are that

1) I get a set of numbers each having a varying number of decimal places.
2) When all is said and done each number is limited to 4 decimal places. 
3) The final SUM() of all numbers in the group must EXACTLY = 1

Comment: Did you mean `decimalPlaces` instead of `places`? You will have to make two passes over the set of numbers. Alternatively, you will have to add or subtract 0.0001 from one number to make the sum equal to one.

Comment: If you need exactly 1, you may get one number as 1 minus sum of another. But exact decimal accuracy won't be met in general case because of binary nature of `double`

Answer (score 0):

There are many conversions in your code between double and BigDecimal. These conversions may be adding double precision error to your values. Please find the below code, all numbers are stored in BigDecimal.

```
    List<BigDecimal> myGroupOfObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    myGroupOfObjects.add(new BigDecimal("0.3"));
    myGroupOfObjects.add(new BigDecimal("0.1"));
    myGroupOfObjects.add(new BigDecimal("0.2"));
    myGroupOfObjects.add(new BigDecimal("0.2"));

    BigDecimal sumOfAllDoublesInGroup = new BigDecimal("0.8"); // #HardCoding

    BigDecimal normalizationFactor = new BigDecimal("1.0")
        .divide(sumOfAllDoublesInGroup);

    BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(0);
    for(BigDecimal myObject : myGroupOfObjects){
        myObject = myObject.multiply(normalizationFactor)
                .setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

        result = result.add(myObject);
    }

Result: 
0.3750
0.1250
0.2500
0.2500
------
1.0
```